# How can one style xml using xslt while keeping the tags in their original order?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Here's the problem. I have an xml file in which there are multiple tags that, depending on who writes them, could end up being in any order. I need to create  an xls file to style it whilst keeping the tags in their original order. Here is the xml:

```
<content>
<h>this is a header</h>
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
<link>www.google.com</link>
<h> another header!</h>
</content>
```

Comment: What is your current XSLT and where are you having problems?

Comment: I find it a little hard to imagine how you have written your code to reorder these elements without trying quite hard to do so. If you showed us your code we would be able to tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: I dont want to reorder the elements... as I said in my post.

Comment: If you won't show your XSLT, will you at least show us what the desired output should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT won't re-order elements on its own, unless you tell it to do so. If you are matching elements, and replacing them with other elements, it will just process them in the order i finds them.

If you are looking to simply replace elements with HTML elements, you would simply write a matching template for each element, where you output the HTML element you need. For example, to replace an **h** element with an **h1** element you could do this

```
<xsl:template match="h">
   <h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </h1>
</xsl:template>
```

The **h1** element will be output in the position the **h** element was in the original document. Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="content">
      <body>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </body>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="h">
      <h1>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </h1>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="link">
      <a href="{text()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </a>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample document, the following is output

```
<body>
   <h1>this is a header</h1>
   <p>this is a paragraph</p>
   <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
   <h1> another header!</h1>
</body>
```